# insert into. while loop, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new one in php, and I have a question.

```
    $result = mssql_query('stored proc. with some parameters');

    while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)){
          mysqli_query('INSERT INTO dbname VALUES ($row[0], $row[1], ... , $row[15] );') or die ('Insertion mistake.');
    }
```

The problem is, I've got die() exception after ~430 insertions. The size of $result query can be up to 100.000 results. I cannot access the MS base and touch stored procedures, and this data transfer in needable. Can somebody help me, with a solution, or show the place, I can read more about that kind of problem?

Comment: Are you running your PHP script from the command line via PHP-cli or from within a web page? I suspect you're running into the 30 seconds timeout. Try to run your script from the commandline as `php -c myscript.php`

Comment: Please, use a column list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a single query might be faster.

```
    $result = mssql_query('stored proc. with some parameters');
    $query = '';
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)){
      $query .= "INSERT INTO dbname VALUES ($row[0], $row[1], ... , $row[15]),"; 
    }

    mysqli_query($query) or die('Insertion mistake.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ore better this I think:

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)){
    $values = "({$row[0]}, {$row[1]}, ... , {$row[15]})";
}
$query = 'INSERT INTO dbname VALUES ' . implode(',', $values);
mysqli_query($query) or die('Insertion mistake.');
```

And I didn't show it, but you need to run the data $row[0], etc... through mysqli_real_escape_string() before inserting.

Also, in the query, you need to quote the data that is not destined for a numeric column type: '{$row[0]}' etc. if it is text.

Comment: The rows in table are stritcly specified. And mysqli_real_escape_string() is no need here - all data is taken from storage, where it stored in "correct" format

Comment: If it is all numeric or the text has no possibility of containing a NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z, then you may be OK.  Also, what does "rows in table are stritcly specified" mean. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running out of memory. You can add to the top of the script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

This will set the maximum memory limit for your script to 512MB. 
You can also try to change `memory_limit`at `php.ini`